# Ebean how to fetch data from multiple tables which have relationship in play framework

Tags: jpa, playframework, hibernate-mapping, playframework-2.2, ebean

I have an sql query that I don't know how I can use it in play framework by fetching records from two different tables:

```
SELECT a.Id as DriverId, a.names as Drivernames, b.bill_no as driverBillNumber, b.DriverId from drivers a join StoreBook b on a.Id = b.DriverId where a.phone_number ='9889'
```

I have two mysql tables `drivers` and `Storebook`. I am able to get the list of data from StoreBook table but unable to access **drivers** table for join .

Look my code:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "StoreBook")
public class Store extends Model {
@Id
public Long id;
@Constraints.Required
public String bill_no;
public int amount;
public String Created_at;


public static Model.Finder<Long, Store> find = new Finder(Long.class, Store.class);


public static List<Store> mystore() {
    return find.all();      
    }
    }
```

**Drivers table** :

```
@Entity
  @Table(name ="drivers")
   public class New_driver extends Model{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "Id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
   public Long Id;
   @Column
   @Constraints.Required
   public String names;
   New_driver(String names) {     
    this.names = names;
   }
    public static void create(New_driver account) {
    account.save();
    }
     }
```

**The following code is used in controllers :**

```
    public class showBooks_history extends Controller {
     public static Result (){
    Form<StoreBook> result = form(StoreBook.class);
    return ok(showbooks.render(StoreBook.mystore(), result));
      }
       }
```

**Code I use for view which is HTML Scala template:**

```
     @( formList: List[Store],form: Form[Store]) )
    @main_dashboard("welcome")
       {
          .....
          <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Driver names</th>
                                <th>Bill number</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                          @for(i <- Store.mystore()) {
                                <tr>
                                    <td><i>names ???</i></td>
                                    <td><i>@i.bill_no</i></td>
                                </tr>
                                }
                               ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have relation in your StoreBook with Driver,
firstly you should specify relation type [(1-1, 1-m, m-m)](http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/mapping/jpa/) 
ex:

```
//in StoreBook.java model
@OneToOne
public Driver driver;
```

then in template:

```
 <tr>
    <td><i>@i.driver.names</i></td>
    <td><i>@i.bill_no</i></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: After what i realized Play ease and summarizes  the long lines  of sql queries we write. thank you so much

Comment: Its not Play feature, its Ebean ORM's feature